# showing div hide automatically after some seconds?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a div which has display:none. On button press I want to show it using jquery. It is shown but just in a second or two it is automatically hidden.

I am not an expert and not able to get where I am doing wrong. Please help me.

```
  <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnCVUpload" Text="Upload" OnClientClick="CVConfirm()" />  <div id="divConfirmCV" style="border: dashed 2px black; background: gray; display:none;">
                A profile can have only one CV, uploading this CV will remove an existing CV. Click
                "Yes" to proceed
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnCVYes" Text="Yes" />
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnCVNo" OnClientClick="HideCVConfirm" Text="NO" />
            </div>




 function CVConfirm() {
            $("#divConfirmCV").css("display","block").show(1000)
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's hidden again because the page is posting back to the server, and you've got a brand new page again with the initial state of the button being hidden. You either want to a) not show the div until the page posts back, in which case you could make the div an asp:panel or something similar and set it to Visible on your button click. Or b) you don't want to use an asp:Button, but a regular `<input type=button>` which would NOT post back to the server, if you just want to show the div without hitting the server again. I'd say by the look of your code you really want to go with option b. So, your code would simply be:

```
<input type=button ID="btnCVUpload" value="Upload" onclick="CVConfirm()" />
```

Of course, your're using jquery so you should really do:

```
<input type=button ID="btnCVUpload" value="Upload" />

<script>
  $(function(){
    $("#btnCVUpload").click(function(){
       $("#divConfirmCV").css("display","block").show(1000);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I really don't miss ASP.NET... Good tip to avoid asp:Button and OnClickclicks!

Comment: Thanks @aquinas, but with asp.net button I am using OnClintClick event, you are right it is posting back but how it can be onClientClick event of button ? any advice please

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. How can it be posting back?

Comment: If you're asking why is it posting back when you have an OnClientClick event. Well, ASP.NET doesn't care that you didn't define a server side click event, it will still happily postback. Now, you *could* also use your ClientClick event and say OnClientClick="HideCVConfirm(); return false;" But that's just ugly. :)

Comment: nice! i almost forgot that "return false;" part, thanks. Also i think it's not ugly :)

Answer (score 1):

i would like to write my jQuery like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#<%=btnCVUpload.ClientID%>").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#divConfirmCV").css("display","block").show(1000);
    });
});
```

preventDefault helps you prevent the default behavior of an element on a specific event, like click. Thus the post back wont happen until you let it :)

Comment: But why? If you don't need an actual postback, then this is overkill. Also, you should be using ClientIdMode=Static instead of <%=btnCVUpload.ClientID%>.

Comment: The default set up of asp.net is Predictable so i dont bother setting it up again

Comment: Yes, but that also means that your JS *has* to be on the page. You can't copy and paste `$("#<%=btnCVUpload.ClientID%>")` into an external JS file. That's a big downside IMO.

Comment: now to think of it, it's really remarkable. thanks for reminding me about that.